# Counting how many times the char sir2 appears in sequence sir1[]

Tags: c

I've got a problem with some chars and i can't figure out how to solve it. It is given a sequence of strings and another string. And I have to count the number of appearances of the string in the sequence of strings. I did the program below but it doesn't work.

main.cpp

```
#include "tipulbool.h"
char sir1[25], sir2;
int n, i, k;
int main (){
    cin>>n;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin>>sir1[i];
    cin>>sir2;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        k += secventa(sir1[i], sir2);
    cout<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

tipulbool.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


int secventa (char sir1[], char sir2);
```

tipulbool.cpp

```
#include "tipulbool.h"

int secventa (char sir1[], char sir2){
    int contor;
    char *p;
    p = strstr(sir1[], sir2);
    if(p)
        contor++;
    while(p){
        p = strstr(p + 1, sir2);
        if(p)
            contor++;
    }
    return contor;
}
```

Comment: *but it doesn't work* Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: [`strstr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) takes two `char const *` pointer parameters that point each to a NUL terminated string.

Comment: This is clearly C and not C++

Comment: well it says "invalid conversion from char to char* "

Comment: @Alex, the `strstr` function takes two `char const *` parameters but `sir2` is a `char`

Comment: so what should I do to convert sir2 into char const* and make the program work well?

Comment: @Alex, please see my answer below

Comment: Yea I've seen your reply but I still don't know what should I replace in my code. I tried to make sir2 as char const* but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex Clarify one thing `sir2` is a single character or a string ?

Comment: @Alex then why is it declared as `char` and not pointer or array ?

Comment: I just modified it now as char array and now it works but it doesn't return the right answer...

Comment: @TonyTheLion, Your comment is backwards.   `cin` `cout` and `iostream` are only in C++, not in C.  A look at the file names shows a `.cpp` extension, again showing that this is C++ code, not C.

Comment: This is C++ code, not C, they are not the same language.  Please replace the 'c' tag with the 'c++' tag.

Comment: one major problem:  the initial str1 is not NUL terminated  Another major problem: the variable 'k' is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int countOfChars(char sir1[], char sir2)
{
   int count = 0;
   char* p = sir1;
   while (*p)
   {
       if (p == sir2)
       {
           ++count;
       }
       ++p;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: it says the same thing... "invalid conversion from char to char* "

Comment: your `secventa` function needs to be rewritten as I've written my 'countOfChars' function. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this code:

```
#include "tipulbool.h"

int secventa (char sir1[], char sir2){
    int contor;
    char *p;
    p = strstr(sir1[], sir2);
    if(p)
        contor++;
    while(p){
        p = strstr(p + 1, sir2);
        if(p)
            contor++;
    }
    return contor;
}
```

gets lost in it self.

suggest:

```
#include "tipulbool.h"

int secventa (char sir1[], char sir2){
    int contor = 0;
    char *p = str1;

    while(NULL != (p = strchr(p, str2) ) )
    {
            contor++;
            p++;
    }
    return contor;
}
```

However, note that

```
1) I used `strchr()` rather than `strstr()` 
   because `str2` is a single char, not a string
2) I removed the repetitive code
3) `str1` MUST be a NULL terminated string, which in the posted code is not the case.
```

regarding this code:

```
#include "tipulbool.h"
char sir1[25], sir2;
int n, i, k;
int main (){
    cin>>n;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin>>sir1[i];
    cin>>sir2;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        k += secventa(sir1[i], sir2);
    cout<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

in C++, an array offset starts with 0 and continues to (length of array -1)

variables that are only used in a single function should (in general) be defined as local/auto variables within that function.

suggest using code similar to the following:

```
#include "tipulbool.h"

int main ( void )
{
    char sir2;

    int n;      // will contain number of char in str1
    int i;      // loop counter
    int k = 0;  // will contain number of occurrence of str2 in str1

    // get count of chars in first string
    cin >> n;

    // allocate room for first string (using C string)
    // +1 to allow for NUL terminator byte
    char *sir1 = new char[n+1];

    // initialize first string
    memset( sir1, 0x00, n+1 );

    // input first string
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> sir1[i];

    // input target char
    cin >> sir2;

    // get count of occurances of str2 in str1
    k = secventa(sir1, sir2);

    cout << k << endl;

    delete [] str1;
    return 0;
}
```

Since this is C++, you might want to look at `vector` or `string`
to simplify the written part of the code even further